# default state of loading in reducer always true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How you guys handle initialstate of your loading state in redux reducer? is it always true? The problem is you have to always set it to false in every single case later in the reducer.

Like so

```
const initState = {
  loading: true,
  data: null,
  error: null
}

export function global(state=initState, action) {
  switch(action.type){
    case FETCHING: 
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
    case FETCH_SUCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
        loading: false
      }
    case FETCH_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload.error,
        loading: false
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

If it's set to false you will have this problem

```
class AClassName extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    props.callAnApi()
  }

  //assume in reducer your loading initialstate is false

  render() {


    this.props.something && return <Redirect to={`/app/${this.props.something}`} />

    return !this.props.loading && <SomethingElse { ...this.props } />
  }
}
```

How to return nothing if it's finished loading. Above problem is that SomethingElse component will still got rendered once which is not what I want. So what's your initialState of loading?

Comment: please add reducers

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Done, updated my question with reducer added.

Comment: I default mine to false and set it to true if need be, in your case on call of api, however I would have put it in componentWillMount instead of the constructor.

To render would first check if loading, which it would be as the first step of the API call would be to dispatch the 'FETCHING' action which would then set loading to true. Then once the render method is hit as the API call is non-blocking, loading will be true, the loading component will display and on success of API call set loading to false.

Answer (score 1):

```
const initState = {
  loading: false,
  data: null,
  error: null
}

export function global(state=initState, action) {
  switch(action.type){
    // Called first thing as part of callAnApi
    case FETCHING: 
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
    case FETCH_SUCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
        loading: false
      }
    case FETCH_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload.error,
        loading: false
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}


class AClassName extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.callAnApi();
  }

  //assume in reducer your loading initialstate is false

  render() {

    this.props.loading && return <SomethingElse { ...this.props } />
    this.props.something && return <Redirect to={`/app/${this.props.something}`} />
  }
}
```

This flow has always worked for me

Answer (score -1):

considering the conditional rendering,

for rendering, `this.props.loading`
should be false
and skipping the rendering,
`this.props.loading` shoule be true.

You can simply merge the
default `initState` when you want
default values `e.g.loading = true`.

```
const initState = {
  loading: true,
  data: null,
  error: null
}

export function global(state = initState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCHING:
      return {
        {
          ...state
        },
        {
          ...initState
        }
      }

    case FETCH_SUCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initState,
        data: action.payload,
      }
    case FETCH_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initState,
        error: action.payload.error,
        loading: false
      }
    default:
      return { ...state,
        ...initState
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: so yeah you still set loading to true first for initialstate, but why you merge initialstate with state?state is already default value is initialstate, see the param of the function.

Comment: Why are you spreading state and initial state when by default state is initial state?

Comment: @JamieAden `state is already default value is initialstate ` its only when reducers are first time loaded not always

Comment: @RemeJuan `state when by default state is initial state` I hope you understand it.The state is not in always initial state.Its going to change with every dispatch of action

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN yes and as soon as the reducer instantiates, which is at app instantiation, it's state is set to that of the initial state, ever future call will update that state, there is no need to be spreading in both the state and the initial state.